# N64 hookup to hdtv

Tags: nintendo-64

I have an rfu adapter for my n64 and it powers on and hooks up OK. But I can't get it to show up on my TV. When I plug it into the antenna in. It's acting like and antenna and I get 3 channels on my TV rather than none when its not. If I put it on 3 or 4 its just static? I don't know what to check next.

Comment: The N64 might just be broken.  It IS 19 years old.

Comment: No its not broken because I tested it on a different older TV with the antenna in and it worked perfectly. But it wasn't my TV so obviously I can't just use it lol I have to connect it to my flat screen.

Comment: Hmm,m then your TV's broken?  There isn't really anything you can do with an RFU to "mess it up" other than, well, not connect it.

Comment: No TV is fine. Turns on and I play it with a gamceube Wii ps2 and nes lol it just has me stumped!

Comment: Do you use the RFU with the other consoles?  The issue might be the specific connection.  Is the RFU connected directly to the TV or another console's RFU?

Comment: It's connected directly to the tv. From the 64 plugged into the antenna in on my TV.

Comment: Been using this for 20 years with no problems: http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/400620840851?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82

Comment: I have that for my gamceube. Would it work the same?

Comment: @CurtisMcIntyre In my experience, it doesn't work but there is no risk trying. I don't see any apparent difference between the connectors for different consoles, which makes it easy to mix them up; I've plugged in the wrong connector and it just didn't work (blank screen) but didn't break anything (swapping in the correct one worked just fine). You can try the gamecube one to see if it works; if not, either a local used games store or ebay can provide you a connector for N64 pretty cheap.

Comment: If you're in North America make sure that your TV is configured so that channel 3 is the old analogue over-the-air channel 3 (NTSC), not the new digital TV channel 3 (ATSC). The channels you are able to receive are presumably digital channels, since almost all analog TV broadcasting ended in North America long ago. If possible though, use the analogue yellow/white/red cable that came with your console to connect to your TV without using the RFU adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Get an S Video or Composite lead for the N64 instead. The image quality will be a lot better and there's no messing around with tuning in the TV.